# Did my new flooring project just become a little more complicated?

Tags: concrete, repair, foundation, subfloor, crack

Pics: https://imgur.com/a/MpIV7uP

I was removing the carpet padding when I found cracks. Home is slab concrete foundation, 60 years old. Thanks!

Comment: Any wettest/dampest/smells/stains from the old padding?  Is the surface flat, no dips/ridges?  Level is different and only matters to you, compared to the floor.

Comment: The new flooring might matter.  carpet and soft vinyl is more forgiving of unflat floors than tile or vinyl planks.  There is usually a small range that flooring can accept in difference of heights.

Comment: Let's hope the moisture on the slab is from some kind of attempt at cleaning, i.e. added after the padding was removed!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing of particular concern for a 60 year old slab there. Appears that they failed to provide control joints to make the cracks neat, that's all. Minor cracking is utterly normal (which is why control joints are good practice) and there's no sign of displacement.